# Is there a way to create ButtonBehavior inside a .kv file?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

**I want to create a ButtonBehavior using Image inside a .kv file,**

I have only created a ButtonBehavior inside the .py file using the example below

```
class Register(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Register,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.source = 'images/registers.png'
    def on_press(self):
        self.source = 'images/registerpop.png'
    def on_release(self):
        self.source = 'images/register.png'
```

***Is there a way to create it inside a .kv file since i want to return the .kv file in the mainApp(App) ?***

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following in kivy file like this

In .kv file

```
Register:
<Register>:
   source: "./images/registers.png"
   on_press:self.source= "./images/registerpop.png"
   on_release:self.source= "./images/register.png"
```

In .py file

```
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.app import App

class Register(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    pass

class myApp(App):
    pass

myApp().run()
```